# add list programmatically sharepoint 2013 from xml parse

Tags: xml, list, loops, sharepoint-2013

currently, I have a task to add list sharepoint 2013 from xml document.

I try to iterate the xml document and i print to standar text field, it's success.

```
foreach (XElement xe in Xdoc.Descendants("node")){ 
     lblText.Text += "\n"+xe.Element("title").Value; 
}
```

but, when I change the print to add list, error happens.

> Sorry, something went wrong An unexpected error has occurred.

```
SPWeb openWeb = site.OpenWeb();    
SPList list = openWeb.Lists["Announcement"];
SPListItem oItem1;

foreach (XElement xe in Xdoc.Descendants("node")){
     oItem1 = list.Items.Add();
     oItem1["Title"] = xe.Element("title").Value;
     oItem1["Body"] = xe.Element("body").Value;
     oItem1["Created"] = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
     oItem1["Modified"] = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1);
     oItem1.Update();
}
```

am I wrong to add list or something else? thank's for helping.

future, I want change value on body and title with html decode.

================================================================

It happens when I run that code on my local sharepoint server. When I try to run in a real server error doesn't appear and the time processing is totally faster. Maybe it doesn't source code problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare and create the SPListItem  object inside the for loop.
Also use list.AddItem() instead of list.Items.Add(), and use TryGetList to get list object , as they are  good coding practice.

```
using(SPWeb openWeb = site.OpenWeb())
{   
SPList list = openWeb.Lists.TryGetList("Announcement");
if(list!=null)
{
    foreach (XElement xe in Xdoc.Descendants("node")){
         SPListItem oItem1= list.AddItem();//Use AddItem instead of items.Add
         oItem1["Title"] = xe.Element("title").Value;
         oItem1["Body"] = xe.Element("body").Value;
         oItem1.Update();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: thank's for your answer.i already try your solution, but "unexpected error occured" happened again. i don't know the error coming from.

Comment: did you try debugging. Check whether xml has "body" element and title.

Comment: i'm sure about that, because i try to print the body of xml node, everything is fine.